# Export two different commands to txt

Tags: terminal, applescript, wifi

This is a very beginner question, but my knowledge of AppleScript and terminal is really limited.

Essentially I want to run two commands and output the results to a single text file on the desktop.

```
ping -t 10 *IPADDRESS* > ~/Desktop/WiFi.txt 

system_profiler SPAirPortDataType > ~/Desktop/WiFi.txt
```

I have been trying to do this in AppleScript, and am expecting the the first command to not always return a result (I'm expecting packet drops) but keep resulting in errors like:

> The command exited with a non-zero status.

An example of how to write this out would be wonderful!

Thanks in advance.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
do shell script "(ping -t 10 www.google.com > ~/Desktop/WiFi.txt || true) && system_profiler SPAirPortDataType >> ~/Desktop/WiFi.txt"
```